# Responsive Website - Sizing Issues?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am currently creating a general responsive template for myself , as I have not really touched this side of design as of yet.

I am having a issue with my "Content Div" when resizing to about 600px (A red border will appear when the resolution is right as to where the problem is). My content div will no longer expand even though I have set a static height of 2300px , so the content just floats outside and the content div does not expand.

```
 @media only screen   
and (max-width : 603px) {  


/* Styles */  
#column_wrapper img {margin-left:25.33%;padding-right: 20%;}
#column1_content{height:500px;}
#column2_content{height:500px;}
#column3_content{height:500px;}
#column_wrapper{border:1px solid red;height:300px;float: left;}
#content{height:2300px;margin-top: 100px;margin-bottom: 20%;}

}
```

The site can be found at [Responsive Template](http://www.jn-design.co.uk/Responsive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens when a floated element is within a container box, that element does not automatically force the container’s height adjust to the floated element. When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow.

You do not need to give height instead for div#content use clearfix. This will fix it ;)

```
.clearfix:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
display: inline-block;
}

 html[xmlns] .clearfix {
display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
height: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Where do I insert the class that this css is styling?

Comment: @JamesNew You need to add above code in your stylesheet at very end and then set class attribute of #column_wrapper to clearfix and remove float:left; from your #column_wrapper ... I see no reason for floating this div. If you think you need ... than you have to set class attribute for both i.e. #content and #column_wrapper

Comment: Have tried this and it does not seem to work , I simply changed the names you gave me to the following  `#column_wrapper:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}

#column_wrapper {
display: inline-block;
}

 html[xmlns] .clearfix {
display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
height: 1%;
} `

Comment: no please do not change names for class clearfix ... just do what I have asked you in my previous comment. and tell me I will look what is the problem.

Comment: Okay , I have uploaded the changes , still seems to have the same problem , not quite expanding?

Comment: Remove height from #content

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20962/discussion-between-james-new-and-imran)

Answer (score 0):

don't use static height in div#content use only overflow:hidden; and remove too the static height in #column1_content, #column2_content and #column3_content

relevant: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: I put the following and it did not work `@media only screen   
and (max-width : 603px) {  


/* Styles */  
#column_wrapper img {margin-left:25.33%;padding-right: 20%;}
#column1_content{height:auto;}
#column2_content{height:auto;}
#column3_content{height:auto;}
#column_wrapper{border:1px solid red;}
#content{margin-top: 100px;margin-bottom: 20%;clear: both;height:auto;}

} `

Answer (score 0):

It's because the elements **inside** are floated.  When you float an element, it takes that element out of the content flow.  This means that those elements aren't going to push out the div and expand it with the content.